# Xamarin.Mac Secure Text Field to move the focus by inputting Enter key

Tags: c#, storyboard, enter, xamarin.mac, setfocus

I would like to move the focus by input enter key after entering a string into a secure text field, but I have no idea how to do it at all.

[image]

Do I define it as an `Outlet`? What do I do then?

I couldn't find anything on Google the following code in fragments only:

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    textPassword.ShouldReturn = (NSSecureTextField) =>
    {
        textPassword.ResignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    };

}
```

Of course, it doesn't work. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you are trying to achieve you will want to go into your storyboard and right click on both your NSTextFields individually.

This will bring up a list of methods that can be utilised
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCtAS.png)

Dragging action into your viewcontroller.h file within xcode will set up the action link for both textfields.

Now in order to link this to your Viewcontroller.cs youll need to add the methods you set up into your viewcontroller.[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mnYa.png)

The code you found on google was close however it seems in order to resignfirstresponder on mac you need to assign first responder to something else.

Looking at the screenshot above i've taken first responder from the emailtextfield(1) and given it to passwordtextfield(2) which seems to be similar to what your looking to do.

Let me know how you get on.

Rob